# how to overcome NullPointerException in android?

Tags: android

I'm having a NullPointerException but I'm unable to find the line were context is null. Whenever program jumps to Mainactivity it throws this exception please help me in finding that line I'll be very thankfull.

```
    package com.example.hurryapppointalert_client;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;;;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
String msg;
static String plat;
static String plong;
AppLocationService appLocationService;
Button bt;
static Button btstop,btmap,btask;
static TextView tv;
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
static Context context;
static MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sec);
context=getApplicationContext();
Data.notimgr.notify(0, Data.noti);
bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
btmap=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btMap);
btstop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btstop);
appLocationService = new AppLocationService(MainActivity.this);
Location location = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (location != null) 
{
Data.ulat = location.getLatitude();
Data.ulong = location.getLongitude();
msg="Location:?"+Data.ulat + "?" + Data.ulong+ "?" + Data.pointNum;
}
else 
{
Toast.makeText(context, "Turn on Wifi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

btmap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!(plat.equals(" ") && plong.equals(" ")))
        {
        double lat=Double.parseDouble(plat);
        double longi=Double.parseDouble(plong);
        String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?&daddr=%f,%f", lat, longi);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        try
        {
        startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex)
        {
        try
        {
        Intent unrestrictedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(unrestrictedIntent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException innerEx)
        {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please install a maps application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
        } 
        else
        Toast.makeText(context, "No latitude and longitude were found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
});

btask.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sms.sendTextMessage("+923313552256", null, "Not Recieved!", null,null); 
        }
});

btstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.stop();
        sms.sendTextMessage("+923313552256", null,"Recieved!", null, null);
        }
});

bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        sms.sendTextMessage("+923313552256", null, msg, null, null);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve location! Turn on GPS and Maps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
});
}//end of onCreate()


public static void startAlarm(String msg,Context context)
{
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, notification);
mp.start();
btstop.setVisibility(1);    
btmap.setVisibility(1); 
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(msg, " ");
plat = tokens.nextToken();
plong = tokens.nextToken();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Data.notimgr.cancel(0);
super.onDestroy();
}
}//end of class
```

logcat:

```
    09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hurryapppointalert_client/com.example.hurryapppointalert_client.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at com.example.hurryapppointalert_client.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:106)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
09-06 19:17:26.089: E/AndroidRuntime(13108):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: The Exception is thrown at line 106, But I don't want to count for myself, could you please post this line here? :P

Comment: Simple `btask` is `null`  because not initializing anywhere

Comment: Eh-Ah! got it! ty :)

Answer (score 3):

You are getting NPE because btask has not been initialized and you are trying to set a listener for it . e.g -

```
btask=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btAsk);
```